# Create slider last WordPress post with bootstrap and PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I want to create a slider of the last post of wordpess, that shows one by one using the bootstrap carousel and the php code that is attached

Currently the code shows the last three post, but I want one to appear on each slide

```
  <?php
 global $post;

$last_posts = get_posts(array('posts_per_page' => 3));

foreach ( $last_posts as $post ) :
 setup_postdata( $post );?>

<div class="last-posts-wrap">
 <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
 <h3><?php the_title();?></h3>
 <p><?php the_excerpt();?></p>
</div>

<?php endforeach;
 wp_reset_postdata();
?>

    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the question, I am guessing you are trying to create carousel from the latest posts. Please check the following example. 3 posts are fetched to render carousel. `active` class is added for the first slide. This may help.

```
<?php
$qargs = array(
    'posts_per_page'      => 3,
    'no_found_rows'       => true,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $qargs );
?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                <?php $active_class = ( 0 === $the_query->current_post ) ? ' active': ''; ?>
                <div class="carousel-item <?php echo esc_attr( $active_class ); ?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'large' ); ?>
                    <h3><?php the_title();?></h3>
                    <p><?php the_excerpt();?></p>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </div><!-- .carousel-inner -->
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Exactly, it works perfectly, thank you very much friend. I will make a more aesthetic example and I will publish it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the HTML for each slide in to the `foreach` loop to render slide for each of the posts.

A simple example:

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <div class="carousel-inner">

    <?php foreach ( $last_posts as $post ): setup_postdata( $post );?>

    <div class="carousel-item active">

      <img class="d-block w-100" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url();?>">

      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h3><?php the_title();?></h3>
        <p><?php the_excerpt();?></p>
      </div>

    </div>

    <?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata();?>

  </div>

  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

There might be some typo somewhere, but this will get you pretty close to what you want. Just add your own customization if needed.